# Are Navigator object values accessible by Javascript frameworks that run server side?

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, navigator

I'm a web application dev/DBA that moved away from active development before server side Javascript frameworks became popular so I know I have a hole in my knowledge set when it comes to this subject.  What I'm looking to find out is: if a visitor makes a content request of a site (page, image, etc) and that site uses a server side Javascript framework, does the site have access to the values from the visitor's Navigator object without serving any generated page content (nothing client side)?

I'm considering enhancing an older API I built some time back and I'd like for the caller to send some Navigator read-only values from their visitor's browser without them sending their visitor page content (the entire process needs to be accomplished during the initial request stage).

May not be possible but the question came up during a brainstorming session and I realized I don't have the expertise to answer that question.

Thanks in advance for any insights/suggestions!

Comment: Node does not have a Navigator API https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v17.x/api/ - Browser (client-side) APIs are not accessible server-side. Hopefully you can get the data another way

Comment: @evolutionxbox - My initial assumption was that they were not accessible but being as I'm unfamiliar with these frameworks, I gotta ask.  As for "another way", I'm not seeing one that doesn't involve accessing the browser's DOM directly so I may need to reexamine the way my API itself works.  Thanks for the confirmation and the link!

Comment: You can see the information sent to the server in Node.js's [http.ClientRequest](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpclientrequest).

Comment: @Yogi - I'm looking for read only attributes like hardwareConcurrency, pdfViewerEnabled, userAgent, language, etc.  I know some of those values are available in the CGI scope but some are not and, if they can be retrieved, I'd like to get them.

Comment: @Dr.Vortex - I'm not at all familiar with Node.js but it looks like I will start learning.  Thanks for the prompt!

Comment: @Yogi - to be fair, I'm not asking for a specific solution but rather posing a general question: for a site that uses a server side Javascript framework, can values from a site visitor's Navigator object be accessed without the site serving any generated page content?  The API I'm going to modify doesn't come into play as the Navigator data is separate from the end use (the API) that I'd put it to.  I could clarify that the API is a web service but the web server/backend of the calling site could be anything.  Web services are rather caller agnostic hence the general nature of the question.

Comment: @Yogi - No, in fact, that's the opposite of what I'm talking about.  A visitor opening a page is "serving content" which is contrary to the circumstance I described.  It appears that what I'm asking about isn't possible.  Indeed, the first response (@evolutionbox 's comment) pretty flatly says it's not possible but being unfamiliar with the frameworks, I needed to ask.  If a visitor has a page then this is no effort for me as I'm well versed with Ajax...but the trick is there can't be a page.  Thanks for the discussion, though.  It's been enlightening.